# JAXWS/OWSM: Unable to find SecurityPolicyFeature class in any jar

Tags: jax-ws

I am creating a JAX WS client to call a webservice. There is a OWSM security policy wss_username_token_service_policy added to it through enterprise manager. To apply the security policy to client i used below code:

```
weblogic.wsee.jws.jaxws.owsm.SecurityPolicyFeature[] securityFeature = new weblogic.wsee.jws.jaxws.owsm.SecurityPolicyFeature[] { new weblogic.wsee.jws.jaxws.owsm.SecurityPolicyFeature(
    "policy:oracle/wss_username_token_service_policy"
)};
```

But I am unable to find SecurityPolicyFeature in weblogic.jar. There is only in one class "PolicySubjectBindingFeature" under weblogic.wsee.jws.jaxws.owsm. I checked in 10.3.3, 10.3.4 and 10.3.5.

Can you please let me know which jar has the SecurityPolicyFeature class in it?

Comment: You can give a nice format to your code by indenting it with four spaces, or surrounding it with backticks like these `

Answer (score 2):

This class is available in ws.api_1.1.0.0.jar located in $MIDDLEWARE_HOME/oracle_common/modules/

Regards,
Vikrant Korde.